# passing xml for a checkout process

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, api

I am a bit confused on how i create and send this call to the url with php....here is the xml i need to create

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mer="http://www.site.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mer:InitializePayment>
         <mer:request>
            <mer:MerchantID>67779987</mer:MerchantID>
            <mer:Password>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</mer:Password>
            <mer:Invoice>12345</mer:Invoice>
            <mer:TotalAmount>1.03</mer:TotalAmount>
            <mer:TaxAmount>0.50</mer:TaxAmount>
            <mer:AVSAddress>4 Corpor</mer:AVSAddress>
            <mer:AVSZip>30329</mer:AVSZip>
            <mer:TranType>PreAuth</mer:TranType>
            <mer:CardHolderName>John Jamed</mer:CardHolderName>
            <mer:Frequency>OneTime</mer:Frequency>
            <mer:CustomerCode>CustCode123</mer:CustomerCode>
            <mer:Memo>HostedCheckoutMemo</mer:Memo>
            <mer:ProcessCompleteUrl>https://somesite/ordercomplete.aspx</mer:ProcessCompleteUrl>
            <mer:ReturnUrl>https://somesite/ShoppingCart.aspx</mer:ReturnUrl>
            <mer:DisplayStyle>Prent</mer:DisplayStyle>
            <mer:BackgroundColor>#FFFFFF</mer:BackgroundColor>
            <mer:FontColor>#000000</mer:FontColor>
            <mer:FontFamily>FontFamily1</mer:FontFamily>
            <mer:FontSize>Medium</mer:FontSize>
            <mer:LogoUrl>https://somesite/images/DurangoPet2.PNG</mer:LogoUrl>
            <mer:PageTitle>Test SoapUI</mer:PageTitle>
            <mer:SecurityLogo>On</mer:SecurityLogo>
         </mer:request>
      </mer:InitializePayment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and here is a sample url i need to send to

```
  https://someplace.net/tws/TransactionService.asmx?wsdl
```

Maybe i am confused because i assumed that making an api call would be like this

```
  https://someplace.net/tws/TransactionService.asmx?wsdl?MerchantID=67779987&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Maybe someone can clear this up for me

```
    array(6) { 
[0]=> string(74) "InitializePaymentResponse InitializePayment(InitializePayment $parameters)" 
[1]=> string(62) "VerifyPaymentResponse VerifyPayment(VerifyPayment $parameters)" 
[2]=> string(77) "AcknowledgePaymentResponse AcknowledgePayment(AcknowledgePayment $parameters)"  
[3]=> string(74) "InitializePaymentResponse InitializePayment(InitializePayment $parameters)" 
[4]=> string(62) "VerifyPaymentResponse VerifyPayment(VerifyPayment $parameters)"
[5]=> string(77) "AcknowledgePaymentResponse AcknowledgePayment(AcknowledgePayment $parameters)" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SOAP (in this instance)  http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php   to use  wsdl services ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language )

as for second part

Usually your SOAP headers woudl have authentication
as indicated in you sampel XML (request)

```
 <mer:MerchantID>67779987</mer:MerchantID>
 <mer:Password>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</mer:Password>
```

Comment: i am looking at the library...how do i add the headers with the password and merchantID

Comment: @Tamer
Firstly you have to look ate the service avlable at  https://someplace.net/tws/TransactionService.asmx?wsdl

`$client = new SoapClient(" https://someplace.net/tws/TransactionService.asmx?wsdl  ");`

then (assuming from you exampel taht teh service is "InitializePayment" you do the request

`$result = $client->InitializePayment(array('MerchantID'=>67779987, "Password"=>"xxxxxx", "otherfileds"=>"values"));`

Comment: $url         = "https://hc.mercurydev.net/tws/TransactionService.asmx?wsdl";
$client     = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
var_dump($client);

Comment: i got this object(SoapClient)#1 (3) { ["trace"]=> int(1) ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(2) of type (Unknown) }

Comment: @Tamer 
try this
`var_dump($client->__getFunctions());`

Comment: click on the link on the previous comment...i will have the functions also

Comment: @Tamer
ok. what you have in taht SOAp object are services avalable via wsdl..

next you have to use soap call to call these fucntion. see http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

your array woudl be parameters in your example xml (i.,e. `$client->__soapCall("InitializePaymentResponse", array(array("MerchantID"=>xxxxxxx), array("Passwrod"=>"aaaaa", etc///));`